# How can .Net 6.0 console app template create the old program style

Tags: visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2022

Using .Net 6.0, when we create a C# project with the Console app template we get only this:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

There is a way to get back to the old program style, it requires a different framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style. Well, guess what? I can't change the framework.

Is there an easier way to get the old template back while still using .Net 6.0?

Editorial: please go here and vote against this (stupid) new template: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/27420

Comment: Just change it to the way you want manually? How often do you actually need to use the new project template? Once a gap year maybe?

Comment: Don't you see a "Don't use top-level statements" checkbox in the new project window?

Comment: @Pieterjan No, I do not see that anywhere. I would really really love to see it, though.

Comment: That's weird... Can you try updating your templates using the command provided in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see a checkbox on the third step (1 = **Create a new project** / 2 = **Configure your new project** / 3 = **Additional information**).

[image: Create console application - additional information]

You might try and update the `dotnet templates` using

```
dotnet new --update-check
dotnet new --update-apply
```